# Error after hosting vue2 app on IIS and reloading

Tags: vue.js, iis, vuejs2

I was Just trying to host vue 2 application on IIS web server . The hosting works in local machine but have and error after reloading. The error is :-

```
manifest.b5c070d….js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
vendor.38ec6bf….js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
app.7b8d427….js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Comment: If you want any assistance, edit the question to include clear details. Nobody can see your screen and know how exactly you hosted the Vue.js app on IIS, and those steps can be wrong if you followed a random guide from the internet.

Comment: The errors you provided do not help to solve the problem, you need to provide your error code and details when loading the page, you can re-edit the question to add more useful information and relevant screenshots.